# Is the E-Cat by Andrea Rossi et al. proof that cold fusion can work?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, cold-fusion

A team of researchers have tested a device (the E-Cat) produced by a team in Italy led by Andrea Rossi and claim that its 'abundant heat production' together with the change in the composition of its fuel during the reaction can only be explained by a low energy nuclear reaction (LENR) - http://www.sifferkoll.se/sifferkoll/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/LuganoReportSubmit.pdf. Despite the fact that they cannot explain exactly how it works should we all now take LENR seriously? Can anyone figure out from the description in the paper how it does work?

Comment: Rossi did not get patents because the effect does not have a theory to explain it.

Comment: It's difficult to see that this question could literally be answered here.

Comment: @CuriousOne - It's too bad you deleted your answer. It was the answer as far as I'm concerned. Rossi is a known crook. He was put in jail for tax fraud and for environmental crimes. Prior to "working" on cold fusion, he "worked" on converting waste into oil. It didn't work. He surreptitiously dumped the toxic waste, thereby costing Milan, Italy a significant environmental cleanup task. When he got out of jail he looked for a new scam. Hello, cold fusion.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16278/2451

Comment: Hi mistermarko, This question fits poorly on Phys.SE for various reasons, e.g., because _non-mainstream physics_ is _off-topic._ I close it as a _duplicate,_ not because it is necessarily an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Comment: 'non-mainstream physics is off-topic.' I find that attitude profoundly appalling. If the guy is wrong it should be possible to prove him wrong. If he's right then it will become mainstream.

Answer (score 4):

Please note, that this test was conducted by exactly the same group that did the previous test, lead by Guiseppe Levi, who is closely connected to Andrea Rossi. Also, you can read from the report, that Rossi himself was present in the test pulling the strings.

Hardly independent testing, is it?

The above facts alone are enough to make the report somewhat fishy, not to mention the lack of any radiation, and the fact, that the isotopic composition of the ashes analysed is highly suspicious, as explained by Swedish physicist Stephan Pomp in his blog.

http://stephanpomp.blogspot.se/2...

No, I don't think this is proof of cold fusion/lenr.

Comment: Is there some kind of civil war going on within Swedish academia that we don't know about?

Comment: @Timo, what do you say to the "six independent observers" mentioned below?  How does that fit it?  Thanks!

Comment: why not to make pair test. I.e. take steel rod vs Rossi machine, feed them both with the same (easy to measure) power and document differences in temp/luminocity etc. It seems to be most direct demonstration possible given experiment description.

Answer (score 2):

Their latest press release says it has been confirmed by 6 independent observers. However, so far I cannot find who these are nor the status of their scientific credentials. If Rossi really has something working I do not see why he does not simply get a whole slew of patents and throw the whole technology wide open for inspection by qualified teams of scientists and engineers. Call me exceedingly skeptical.

Comment: OTOH, maybe Rossi should have put all of their information up front. OK - info here 

http://www.forbes.com/sites/markgibbs/2013/05/20/finally-independent-testing-of-rossis-e-cat-cold-fusion-device-maybe-the-world-will-change-after-all/

Comment: Having said that, there are now only two possibilities. Either this device is exhibiting some new form of energy conversion that goes beyond classical chemical energy. Or Rossi is an outright fraud.

Comment: I really want this to be real as well! And all those conventional fusion approaches that are being undertaken by private enterprise. Once we have cheap clean energy almost anything is possible.

Comment: I am confused by the comments here: can anyone **state the names** of the "six independent observers"?  if so, thanks!

Comment: @JoeBlow - The names are on the linked paper in the question.

Comment: I see - thanks.  It does seem to be the case they are "not very independent"